# Adding overflow to a div prevents its contents from dragging properly

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui

I'm using the jquery FullCalendar plugin, and I'm adding external events to a calendar.

Everything works perfectly from [this example](http://arshaw.com/js/fullcalendar-1.5.4/demos/external-dragging.html). However, I  have a lot of external events that need to be dragged onto the calendar, so my list of events needs to scroll.

I added:

```
overflow-y: auto;
```

to the parent div, which does allow it to scroll. However, the events disappear when they are dragged outside the parent div.

[Here is a JSfiddle of what happens](http://jsfiddle.net/9TmPE/)

I've tried as many combinations of z-index and overflow combinations as I can, and they keep disappearing when they leave the parent.

How can I allow the parent div to scroll and prevent the event items from disappearing when dragged?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If this is the initialization of your [Draggable](http://jsfiddle.net/AaronBlenkush/9TmPE/2/):

```
$(this).draggable({
    zIndex: 999,
    revert: true, // will cause the event to go back to its
    revertDuration: 0, //  original position after the drag
    scroll: false,
    //INSERT HERE
});
```

Then insert one of the following options at the `//INSERT HERE` line:

### Option 1

```
    helper: 'clone',
    appendTo: 'body'
```

This will work as desired, but the dragged element will be cloned upon dragging.

To avoid that, use the next option:

### Option 2

```
    helper: function(event, ui) {
        var clone = $(this).clone();
        $(this).css({opacity:0}); //or $(this).hide()
        return clone;
    },
    stop: function(event, ui) {
        $(this).css({opacity:1}); //or $(this).show()
    },
    appendTo: 'body'
```

[See this Fiddle for an example](http://jqueryui.com/draggable/).

---

If you need to actually "move" the element (i.e. it doesn't reappear after dropping it), you'll need to `remove()` the element once it's been dropped in the proper place. You could add something to the `receive` callback of the [Droppable](http://jqueryui.com/droppable/) that removes the original element.